# Is it possible to create an input with an editable default value?

Tags: python, input

I am a python newbie and currently fiddling with it in various ways.

But I'm kind of stuck at creating an input with editable default value.

For example,

if you run input, there will be default value which you can change or leave it be.

Is it possible to create such input with standard library?

Comment: By default do you mean clicking enter ?

Comment: For example, if default = 'hello', 'hello' will appear when I run input. And I can change 'hello' in real time.

Comment: Are you asking to change the text variable `defualt` as you type?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Yes. That's exactly what I wanted to know!!!

Comment: You may want to re-type your question then, just to make it a bit more obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test whether the user has inputted anything then if they haven't replace it:

```
default_val = 'Default answer'
inp = input("Enter a string (default value is: '"+default_val+"'): ")
if not inp:
    inp = default_val
print(inp)
```

This outputs:

```
Enter a string (default value is: 'Default answer'): 
Default answer
```

or

```
Enter a string (default value is: 'Default answer'): Different answer
Different answer
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.
But what I really want to do is to edit the default value when you type the input.
When the input is ran, default value will appear, you can edit it real time.

Comment: So you want a variable which you can edit with the input?

Answer (score 1):

```
default = 'spam'
user_input = input(f"Enter a string (default: {default}):") or default
print(user_input)
```

output:

```
Enter a string (default: spam): # user hit Enter
spam
```

Note, this assumes user input will never be empty string (i.e. empty string is not valid input for your use case).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Perhaps my explanation was deficient.
What I really want to do is to edit the default value when you type the input.
When the input is ran, default value will appear, and you can edit it real time.

Answer (score 0):

Using `input`

```py
default = "foo"

while default != "quit":
    default = input(f"Enter a value ({default}): ")
```

Where you need to click enter each time, and quit by typing `quit`